# Transfer CD music into files without any frequency loss

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, ripping

I bought a [binaural brainwave CD](http://www.hemi-sync.com/). The music is embedded with specific frequencies to affect brainwave in the human brain. It works. As far as I know, the left and right channels are different. They interfere in the brain and create the required frequency.

Now I would like to transfer it into digital files and play it via my smartphone. But, it is known that regular MP3 compressing destroys the frequency.

Is there any software to transfer it without any loss? Large file size is acceptable.

Requirements:

- No loss
- Free
- Works on Windows
- Files can then be played on Windows/Mac/Linux/Android without major trouble

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add on which OS(es) it should run and whether it must be free (or the budget you're willing to spend)? Besides: "Howto" questions are off-topic here. I've slightly altered your text so it matches our site.

Comment: [Google 'rip cd to wav'](https://www.google.nl/search?q=rip+cd+to+wav) should give you all you need

Comment: Added Windows requirement, please edit promptly if you want another OS, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go lossless.

This is a software recommendations site and [cuetools](http://cuetools.net/wiki/Main_Page) is the ripper I favour on windows. On linux, the *pedant's choice* would be [cdparanoia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdparanoia)

FLAC does some compression - but this is of *data* not psycoacoustic compression. This should work well enough.

If you want no compression at all, just use wav files.

Comment: This comment relates to the file formats mentioned, not the SW recommendation.  Just to be clear as to what Journeyman Geek is saying regarding file formats (and if I understand correctly), neither FLAC nor WAV formats will modify the bits in any way.  FLAC will compress them, but they are compressed in a completely lossless manner.  (Imperfect ripping, on the other hand, which is the norm, will definitely modify the bits.)

Answer (score 3):

My tool of choice is [Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/en/index.php/resources/download/) (Windows). As the name suggests, it can be used to create very precise copies of audio tracks. Just make sure you don't select the "fast" option when you first run it. Choosing fast will do less error correction in case of read errors or sync errors.

Exact Audio Copy can save to uncompressed WAV files (be sure to select CD quality in that case, so you get the full 44.1kHz, 16 Bit stereo sound) and can also compress to almost anything. Besides WAV, [FLAC](https://xiph.org/flac/) (Free Lossless Audio Codec) is something you should read about, but you might have some trouble playing it on the smartphone.

Please note that for a precise playback, you might need a good soundcard and good headphones. I'm not sure if a smartphone can keep up with that. The frequencies may suffer from [harmonic distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_harmonic_distortion) and non-linear [frequency response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response).

Before you start anything, check if the CD is a regular audio CD, a HQCD/HDCD (20 bit) or maybe even an Audio DVD (up to 192 kHz, 24 bit, 5.1 channels). They may be hard to distinguish and might need special equipment. I've never had the chance to test if EAC work with these media.

Comment: +1 I don't know of any other way to accurately rip an audio CD.  (Although if others know, please post your comments/answers.)  Exact Audio Copy (EAC) has many confusing options, but it is amazing.  Most software "ripping" tools simply put the optical drive into "fast" mode and rip very inaccurate copies of the media.  With EAC, you can do everything possible to ensure you get a bitwise copy.  You will quickly learn that tiny media defects and minor scratches will be your nemesis.